# How is admob detecting the location

Tags: android, admob

can anyone please tell me how admob is getting his current location to display the suitable ad-language.

I finished my multilanguage app and want to implement admob.

Now I dont know how admob detects the phones location. Does admob this manage itself or do I have to set this manually (create banners for all languages my app supports)?

I havent find any answer, thanks! (Im new to admob)

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about publishing or advertising? If publishing then Admob handles everything. If advertising, then I suspect that Admob will handle everything if you are using a text ad.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Its about advertising. Banners are displayed in mylanguage. Hope this will work in other countrys